# How to make Serverless return 404 instead of 403 for non-existing endpoints?

Tags: serverless-framework

I tried the Serverless framework following the instructions to create the Hello World application. Everything works well, calling the `[url]/dev/hello-world` returns 200 response with the json output as expected.

By default, looks like the response for non-existing endpoints is 403 http status code with json `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`.

I'd like to host a website using the framework.
Is there any way to make the Serverless return 404 instead of 403 for non-existing endpoints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning a 403 instead of 404 is a [deliberate design decision](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216684&tstart=0).

> This is a pattern that is used in many other AWS APIs (most notably S3). In S3, if the user would have had permissions to the see presence of the key (via the ListBucket permission), a 404 will be returned; otherwise a 403 will be returned. Because API Gateway enables permissions at the method level, we can't know whether or not the user should be permitted to have knowledge of the existence of the API resource level, and default to the 403 as a result.

You can elect to catch all missing API methods using a {proxy+} pattern.

```
events:
  - http:
      path: {proxy+} # catch any path not specified elsewhere
      method: get    # or change to any method if you prefer
```

Comment: Really nice finding! Now I understand well why the service returns 403. And the workaround worked like a charm, I just modified it by set `method: all` to return 404 for not-found resouces in all http verbs. Thank you Trent!

Comment: Trent - does the events property go at the root of the serverless.yml, or does it go elsewhere?

Comment: It goes inside a function you write to catch all other URLs in your api gateway. See here for the structure of `serverless.yml`: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

Comment: to get the above to work with serverless-offline, I had to prefix {proxy+} with a /. To get it to work for any method, I also had to use "any" instead of "all".

Answer (score 0):

I did something a bit different its not relavent to API calls, but it is to the final goal of using serverless to host a  website in the CloudFrontDistribution section I added this.

```
CustomErrorResponses:
     ErrorCode: 403
     ResponseCode: 404
     ResponsePagePath: /404.html
```